# Backward elimination in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-science, feature-selection

Can we use for loop and if in backward elimination to do it easily instead of doing it one by one?

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm
X = np.append(arr = np.ones((50, 1)).astype(int), values = X, axis = 1)
X_opt = X[:, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
regressor_OLS = sm.OLS(endog = y, exog = X_opt).fit()
regressor_OLS.summary()
X_opt = X[:, [0, 1, 3, 4, 5]]
regressor_OLS = sm.OLS(endog = y, exog = X_opt).fit()
regressor_OLS.summary()
X_opt = X[:, [0, 3, 4, 5]]
regressor_OLS = sm.OLS(endog = y, exog = X_opt).fit()
regressor_OLS.summary()
X_opt = X[:, [0, 3, 5]]
regressor_OLS = sm.OLS(endog = y, exog = X_opt).fit()
regressor_OLS.summary()
X_opt = X[:, [0, 3]]
regressor_OLS = sm.OLS(endog = y, exog = X_opt).fit()
regressor_OLS.summary()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that with the code below:

```
def backwardElimination(x, sl):
    numVars = len(x[0])
    for i in range(0, numVars):
        regressor_OLS = sm.OLS(y, x).fit()
        maxVar = max(regressor_OLS.pvalues).astype(float)
        if maxVar > sl:
            for j in range(0, numVars - i):
                if (regressor_OLS.pvalues[j].astype(float) == maxVar):
                    x = np.delete(x, j, 1)
    regressor_OLS.summary()
    return x

SL = 0.05
X_opt = X[:, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
X_Modeled = backwardElimination(X_opt, SL)
```